# React-pdf как верстать инпуты

Tags: reactjs, pdf

Передо мной стоит задача сверстатть макет для PDf. я выбрала бибилотеку react-pdf https://react-pdf.org/. но у меня анкета в ней много инпутов. Подскажите, есть ли возможность как-то отборажать их с использованием этой библиотеки или какую-то другую библиотеку? так же я пыталась использовать эту библиотеку https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf-html, но там тоже инпуты не отображаются. Для просмотра я использую PDF viewer из react-pdf.